# Will this work out (usb hub + rpi zero w + Zishan Z1 DSD)?

Tags: usb, power, pi-zero-w, usb-power, usb-hub

Well, I want to connect Rpi zero W and Zishan Z1/2 DSD in one case, but with both devices working in one port connected to PC. (with working usb device in Rpi if in "portable" mode or in both situations)

So, the most easiest way to do it is obvious USB-hub. But if I connect this in USB 2.0 (max 0.5A) will there enough power to working both devices? If Rpi takes [~170mA](https://raspi.tv/2017/how-much-power-does-pi-zero-w-use) and Zishan takes - I don't know (I tried to find out but I guess it is around 500mA).

I want to work Rpi from Zishan's battery ("portable" mode), also, with working gamepad (or wireless reciever like for xbox's ones) (I forgot to show it on picture - with another USBhub or with USB switch (what is unlikely))
So do i think in right way? Will it work? Is there a easier way to do it?

How I think it will work
[image: How I think it will work]

Zishan Z1 DSD
[image: Zishan Z1 DSD]

Rpi Zero W (one MicroUSB port for charging, another for OTG but still usable as charging)
[image: Rpi Zero W]

Comment: Zishan Z1 looks ugly but sounds good: https://tr.aliexpress.com/item/32807427355.html

Comment: Also it dont have such things like playlists and moving from folder to folder ;_;

Comment: Well, but there is no touch screen, and I might lose face if my friends notice that its volume knob is not 24k gold plated, :) (1) Sony DMP-Z1 Digital Music Player (US$10,000.00!)
https://www.amazon.com/Sony-DMP-Z1-Digital-Music-Player/dp/B07K69MT45

(2) Sony DMP-Z1 Review
(2a) https://www.whathifi.com/reviews/sony-dmp-z1-hands-on-review
(2b) https://personalaudio.hk/2019/01/28/sony-dmp-z1-review-2/

Comment: Well, I guess you have bad friends or you wind yourself up.(or you are trolling me -_-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your config is OK.

ZiShan Z1 should take much less than 50mA.  RpiZ takes less than 300mA.  In other words, a piece of cake for USB2.0 hub.

***References***

*Zishan DSD Pro Battery = 3000mAh Battery life = 8H (3000 / 8 ~= 40 mA)*

http://audiorealviews.site/index.php/2019/03/24/zishan-dsd-pro-realview/

*How much power does the Pi4B use? Power Measurements (RpiZ shooting 1080p video ~= 250mA)*

https://raspi.tv/2019/how-much-power-does-the-pi4b-use-power-measurements

Comment: You are welcome.  Happy gaming!